# Difference between openurlconnection vs connect?

Tags: java, android, url, httpurlconnection

I am using HttpURLConnection package to download a large file. I am able to do so but I am bit confuse between HttpURLConnection.connect vs URL.openurlconnection methods.

The URL.openurlconnection returns HttpURLConnection. So can I reuse this object ? If the network disconnects and then connects back, I would like to continue downloading the file. Can I directly call connect() or do I have to reconfigure the connection ?

Link to the documentation:
HttpURLConnection: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html
URL: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Difference between openurlconnection vs connect?

They are equivalent.

> The `URL.openurlconnection` returns `HttpURLConnection`. So can I reuse this object ? If the network disconnects and then connects back, I would like to continue downloading the file. Can I directly call connect() or do I have to reconfigure the connection ?

A HttpURLConnection instance is used to make a single request.  It cannot be reused.  If you want to continue downloading a file following failure, you need to create a new connection.

If you want to avoid transferring again the part of the file that you fetched previously, you could use a ["Range Retrieval Request"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.2).  But be aware that server-side support for range retrieval is optional, so the client-side needs to pay close attention to the response headers to figure out whether it is getting the entire file or just the requested range.

Related Question:

- [Java server side sending file with resume support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011446/java-server-side-sending-file-with-resume-support)