# How to set range header from client with pdf.js?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js, pdf-viewer

I am quite new to client side programming. I am trying to view my pdf in my web using pdf.js. By following the steps in documentation i tried loading pdf with pdf.js. The entire pdf file is getting downloaded in a single request. Now, I would like to do progressive loading (downloading by specifying the range).

I have done the following things at my client and server side.

My client contains two files

1. form.js and
2. index.html

**CLIENT**
**form.js**

```
'use strict';
var PDF_PATH = ""; //Path of pdf file in web
var PAGE_NUMBER = 1;
var PAGE_SCALE = 1.5;

function renderPage(div, pdf, pageNumber, callback) {
        pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
        var scale = 1.5;
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

        var pageDisplayWidth = viewport.width;
        var pageDisplayHeight = viewport.height;

        var pageDivHolder = document.createElement('div');
        pageDivHolder.className = 'pdfpage';
        pageDivHolder.style.width = pageDisplayWidth + 'px';
        pageDivHolder.style.height = pageDisplayHeight + 'px';
        div.appendChild(pageDivHolder);

        // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = pageDisplayWidth;
        canvas.height = pageDisplayHeight;
        pageDivHolder.appendChild(canvas);

       // Render PDF page into canvas context
       var renderContext = {
        canvasContext: context,
        viewport: viewport
       };
       page.render(renderContext).promise.then(callback);

       // Prepare and populate form elements layer
       var formDiv = document.createElement('div');
       pageDivHolder.appendChild(formDiv);
    
 //setupForm(formDiv, page, viewport);
  });
}


function pageLoaded() {
PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
PDFJS.workerSrc = "./pdf.worker.js";   // no i18n
PDFJS.getDocument({url: PDF_PATH}).then(function (pdf) {

        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.setAttribute("id", "pageCanvas");
        canvas.setAttribute('style', "display:none");
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);

        // Rendering all pages starting from first
         var viewer = document.getElementById('viewer');
         var pageNumber = 1;
         renderPage(viewer, pdf, pageNumber++, function pageRenderingComplete() {
                if (pageNumber > pdf.numPages) {
                return; // All pages rendered
                }
                // Continue rendering of the next page
                renderPage(viewer, pdf, pageNumber++, pageRenderingComplete);
        });
});
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  if (typeof PDFJS === 'undefined') {
    alert('Built version of PDF.js was not found.\n' +
          'Please run `gulp generic`.');
    return;
  }
```

and my **index.html** just loads the above js (form.js) and pdf.js and pdf.worker.js files

**SERVER**

This contains a servlet in which i have done the following

1. Option to seek and read the file content from specific byte range by obtaining value from "Range" header in the request
2. Have added `Accept-Range:Bytes` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Accept-Ranges` values in response headers

Now I got struck in the following

> 1.Where to add "Range" header value?
>
> 2.How to send range request from client?
>
> 3.From where these calls were made?
>
> 4.Should I include viewer.html?

Please help me with this ! I'm collapsed :-(

Comment: See https://github.com/joepie91/pdfy/blob/master/public_html/modules/download.php as a reference

Comment: I don't know about PHP @async5.. Sounds very new to me :-( Can you share me some other link please...

Comment: Your question is related to resumable download in java (not to PDF or PDF.js). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011446/java-server-side-sending-file-with-resume-support/5013071#5013071

Comment: Yes @async5 it is something like resumable download I guess since pdf.js has option for `progressive downloading` by specifying `Range` header value. I am not aware of where to set it in the client side...

Comment: FWIW client code looks reasonable. You don't have to do anything on client side. If HTTP range requests are working properly -- PDF.js will just use them.

Comment: My Server is capable of supporting range request. I am not sure from where should I invoke range request from my client..

Comment: You can verify your server with [default PDF.js viewer](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/releases/tag/v1.6.210) -- you shall see 206 responses in the devtools similar to the [demo viewer](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html). The demo viewer does not do anything different than your code (except using disableWorker=false). Please add link to the live demo/example on your server if you still have issues.

Comment: PDF.js does not use range requests for files less than 128kb

Comment: From where he is getting the pdf source in the sample @async5.. I couldn't find... Can you please help me with this..

Comment: Tried with pdf greater than 128 kb size still it is getting entire file in a single request

Comment: Also tried with disableWorker=false/true this doesn't have any impact on range requests..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1.Where to add "Range" header value?

PDF.js detects if server returns "[Accept-Ranges:Bytes](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/7f6a607ea537a6237802fe11e211afb2b19af9cf/src/core/network.js#L370)"  If server returns valid HTTP request headers ([per spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233)), PDF.js (will abort main requests for platforms that does not allow incremental XHR and) will issue range requests.

> 2.How to send range request from client?

PDF.js does that automatically via XHR when it decides that server can handle range requests.

> 3.From where these calls were made?

See [network.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/7f6a607ea537a6237802fe11e211afb2b19af9cf/src/core/network.js) file.

> 4.Should I include viewer.html?

No

Looks like currently the servlet that provides PDF data does not support valid HTTP range request protocol. Just setting "Accept-Ranges:Bytes" is not enough. See [how it's implemented in PHP](https://github.com/joepie91/pdfy/blob/master/public_html/modules/download.php) at  or check previously answered [question related to servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011446/java-server-side-sending-file-with-resume-support/5013071#5013071).

Comment: It must be "Accept-Ranges" @async5 in server side which is what i have missed. I have added it as "Accept-Range" instead :-(

Comment: Please edit the answer with "Accept-Ranges" ... It might be useful for all of us..